# Angular copy image to clipboard over http

Tags: angular, http, copy, clipboard

I have this code to cop image to clipboard in Angular

```
  private _copy(): void {
    domtoimage.toBlob(
      document.getElementById('divToCopy'),
      {
        crossOrigin: 'anonymous',
      }
    )
      .then(
        (blob: Blob) => {
          navigator.clipboard.write(
            [
              new ClipboardItem(
                {
                  "image/png": blob,
                },
              ),
            ],
          );
        },
      );
  }
```

I use this function in domain like: http:// mydomain.com, But image not copied and I got this error

> clipboarditem is not a constructor

Because the domain is over http.

Any help please

Comment: Where exactly you got this error. I just tried a version of you code in my typescript code: `await navigator.clipboard.write([new ClipboardItem({'text/plain': new Blob([JSON.stringify(config)], { type: 'text/plain' }),}),]);` and it is working

Comment: It worked on localhost, but try it online without https(ssl). Image will not be copied.